# Unable to pull phonegap project from github and build successfully

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I've pulled a new phonegap project from github that another developer on my team checked in. I have phonegap (3.1.0) installed (I'm able to build phonegap projects that I've created just fine). When I try to run

```
phonegap build ios
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while building the ios project... platforms/ios/cordova/build: No such file or directory
```

There is a platforms/ios/.gitignore file (created by phonegap when creating the project) that contains the following:

```
*.mode1v3
*.perspectivev3
*.pbxuser
.DS_Store
build
www/phonegap.js
```

So it makes sense there is no build directory cordova/build, so I figured I'd create it. Now I get this error:

```
An error occurred while building the ios project... platforms/ios/cordova/build: is a directory
```

Am I missing something here? What do I need to so that multiple developers can build?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same issue - here's what solved it for me:

In `.gitignore`, change:

`build`

to:

`build/`

and remove the build directory that you created. It is actually a file, not a directory, and there is a bug in the included `.gitignore` - it should only be ignoring `build/` directories, but it is mistakenly also ignoring the (necessary) `platforms/ios/cordova/build` script, so that is why you don't have it.

You will have to restore the `build` file yourself. In a temporary directory, create a new throwaway project and add the ios platform:

`$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

`$ cordova platform add ios`

Take the `platforms/ios/cordova/build` script that gets generated and put it in your real project.

Comment: I use subversion, and had a global svn_ignore setting for `build` directories, so this file got purged on checkout. Restoring from a dummy project worked fine, thanks!